# My Decision Tree implementation is too slow. How can I make it faster or am I doing it all wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, decision-tree

I'm trying to implement a decision tree from scratch, but when I test it using the bluebook dataset from Kaggle, it's way too slow. Here's the code I've written so far. The Node class just contains attributes.

```
class Node():
# the node of the decision tree
# goes left if less than or equal to threshold and right if greater than threshold
# column is the 
def __init__(self, average, column=None, threshold=None, error=None, parent=None, left=None, right=None, is_leaf=False):
    self.average = average
    self.column = column
    self.threshold = threshold
    self.error = error
    self.parent = parent
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    self.is_leaf = is_leaf
```

The DecisionTree class builds the decision tree. The important functions are the `create_tree` and `split` functions. Here's the code for it.

```
class DecisionTree():

    def __init__(self, x, y, min_samples_leaf=1):
        #x is the dataframe with independent variables
        self.x = x
        #y is the dependent variable (price)
        self.y = y
        #min_samples_leaf is the minimum number of items in the leaf
        self.min_samples_leaf = min_samples_leaf
        self.create_tree()

    def create_tree(self):     
        initial_avg = self.y.mean()
        initial_error = math.sqrt(((self.y - initial_avg)**2).sum()/len(self.y))
        initial_idx = np.arange(len(self.x))
        self.root = Node(average=initial_avg, error=initial_error)
        self.split(initial_idx, self.root)

    def split(self, idx, parent_node):
        #idx are the indexes of the rows that are a part of the node
        columns = self.x.columns
        parent_is_leaf = True
        best_error = parent_node.error
        best_column = columns[0]
        best_threshold = 0
        best_left_error = sys.float_info.max
        best_right_error = sys.float_info.max
        best_left_idx = array([])
        best_right_idx = array([])
        #loop through columns
        for col in columns:
            for value in self.x[col].unique():
                left_idx = np.where(self.x[col].iloc[idx] <= value)
                right_idx = np.where(self.x[col].iloc[idx] > value)
                if len(left_idx) < self.min_samples_leaf or len(right_idx) < self.min_samples_leaf:
                    continue
                left_error = self.find_error(left_idx)
                right_error = self.find_error(right_idx)
                if left_error < best_error and right_error < best_error:
                    best_error = (left_error + right_error)/2
                    best_column = col
                    best_threshold = value
                    best_left_error = left_error
                    best_right_error = right_error
                    best_left_idx = left_idx
                    best_right_idx = right_idx
                    parent_is_leaf = False

        if parent_is_leaf:
            parent_node.is_leaf = True
        else:
            parent_node.column = best_column
            parent_node.threshold = best_threshold
            left_node = Node(average=find_average(best_left_idx), error=best_left_error, parent=parent_node)
            right_node = Node(average=find_average(best_right_idx), error=best_right_error, parent=parent_node)
            parent_node.left = left_node
            parent_node.right = right_node
            self.split(best_left_idx, left_node)
            self.split(best_right_idx, right_node)

    def find_error(self, idx):
        #rmse
        avg = self.y.iloc[idx].mean()
        return math.sqrt(((self.y.iloc[idx] - avg)**2).sum()/len(idx))

    def find_average(self, idx):
        #average
        return self.y.iloc[idx].mean()
```

The problem is in the split function. Specifically, these lines:

```
 left_idx = np.where(self.x[col].iloc[idx] <= value)
 right_idx = np.where(self.x[col].iloc[idx] > value)
```

It takes a long time to iterate through all of the possible values of a column to use to split the data. It takes such a long time that when running the code, the recursion doesn’t even happen. Is there a way to speed this up or am I on the wrong path all together?

Here's a diagram of what I'm trying to do. Except instead of classification it's regression.
[image]

Comment: I don't get what you're doing.    You're not looking through every value in A column, you're looking through every value in EVERY column.  Wouldn't such a tree usually be based on one column only?

Comment: @TimRoberts think this type of tree is supposed to be based on all of the columns. It's supposed to be able to predict a value based on a bunch of independent values like column A, B, and C.

Comment: You're right, I withdraw my objection.

Answer (score 0):

Assessing every value for a column is the basic algorithm, but it leads to a lot of unnecessary computations. A workaround to avoid this is to sort the values in ascending order and assess only splitting values that are such that the classes on their left and right are different.

Let's assume you get to a column with the values [0, 4, -8, -4, -6] and the corresponding class label for each instance is [c2, c1, c1, c2, c1]. Using your approach, you have to assess 5 splitting values before finding the right split. The number splitting candidates can be reduced to only 2 by sorting. The following figure shows the sorted result of the column's values. For each value, the corresponding class level is above the line.
[image: Sorted values for a given column]

It can be seen on the figure that splitting at -8 is not going to be effective since the value just right after is from the same class label. So it is not necessary to try this split. However, splitting at -6 is promising since the value just right after it is from a different class. Similarly, -4 is a promising split since the value just at its left is from a different class. Instead of trying -6 and -4, an improvement is obtained by trying only the center of -6 and -4, that is (-6 + (-4))/2 = -5. Elsewhere, it is not necessary to assess the split at the edges. To summarize, valid split candidates are the center of any two values that are from different class label
[image]

I hope this help